# Connecting a Galaxy S3 to my MacBook Pro 10.10.5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, macos

I am trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone to my OS X 10.10.5, with no luck.

I have tried all sorts of different cables, and have checked USB debugging. The phone successfully charges when plugged in to my computer. But it doesn't show up in Android File Transfer or adb devices.

What should I do? Do I have to install a driver of some sort? I have read mixed reviews of something called Kies, some saying DONT install it, others saying DO install it.

Update: I tried downloading Kies, and not only can I still not see my device, but Kies says that I cannot use Android File Transfer as long as Kies is installed, and that I need to uninstall Kies. WTF Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exact same problem when I first started android development. My One Plus One would simply not show up in Android File Transfer. I would highly recommend that you re-install Android File Transfer.

1. Install [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) app.
2. Reboot your Macbook Pro after installation
3. Plug in the usb cable into your mac and start android file transfer.

Let me know if this helped or not!

Comment: OK, I'm going to uninstall Kies and try this now!

Comment: Just a fyi, if you see the android icon jumping up and down in your application tray after you plugged in your phone, then your set.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work still. I uninstalled Kies, reinstalled AFT, tried a bunch of different cables.

Comment: Check out this Link: http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

Comment: Try plugging the cord into different usb ports. If that fails, try a usb hub. I have a similar issue with usb ports not working on my PC.

Comment: I stuck it in all the holes as well as my USB hub. My USB hub doesn't even charge it, but none of the other holes show up (although they charge it fine)

Comment: Have you tried wireless debugging?

Comment: Wireless debugging is possible? I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah you can without root!